# Why does linkedlist.java not export the Node class

Tags: java, linked-list

The Linkedlist.java has a Node class which is never exported, instead it uses and Iterator to allow clients to loop through details.  Why is the Node class not public ? If there was some reason to chose that way what was the thinking ?

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

Comment: It's an implementation detail.

Comment: information hiding, encapsulation

Comment: As an abstraction, you want to see the elements contained within the list; how they are stored doesn't (and shouldn't) matter to an outside observer, so Nodes are hidden from an external programmer.  Instead, functions on the LinkedList are given that do all the Node magic, letting a programmer focus merely on the idea of a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Node` class isn't part of the official Java API. It's an implementation detail, and so it's hidden by making it `private`. If it were exposed by making it `public`, that might make people think it's safe to use, which would be misleading since not all Java implementations will use it. For example, the OpenJDK6 implementation of `LinkedList` has no `Node` class. Instead, it has an [`Entry`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.Entry) class.

Comment: yeah thats a good point, also we can freely modify internals in future releases without breaking dependents

Comment: @JavaDeveloper - Yup. Comparing your source link and my source link, it looks like OpenJDK changed the internal name from `Entry` to `Node` between JDK6 and JDK7.

Answer (score 1):

It is just used for the internal implementation of `LinkedList` and not intended for public usage.

None of the interfaces implemented by `LinkedList` do require a `Node` class so it is perfectly fine to hide such details.

Comment: yeah it means node is only required by linkedlist, just one of the concrete classes that implement collection interfaces. No other concreate class like arraylist would ever need to use Node class.